# Unable to resolve name org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, dialect

Last week I said "let's try out the WildFly 10!" and after the basic configurations and the HelloWorld stuff I wanted to see how does the persistence work. A took my old ABC EAR having a JPA module, where Hibernate is used with SQLite. I set the dialect provided by [net.kemitix](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.kemitix%7Csqlite-dialect%7C0.1.0%7Cjar).

So, I set its dependency in POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.kemitix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and after packaging the EAR looks like this:

```
ABC_Ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear
    lib
        ABC_Jpa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
        sqlite-dialect-0.1.0.jar
        sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar
```

The persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ABC_Jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
        <class>abc.jpa.User</class>
        <class>abc.jpa.Group</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/ABC.db"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/AbcEntityManagerFactory" />
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/AbcEntityManager"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

During the deployment the following exception occurs:

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'ABC_Jpa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar#ABC_Jpa'
WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."ABC_Jpa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar#ABC_Jpa": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."ABC_Jpa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar#ABC_Jpa": org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
```

I tried also to load the JAR containing the dialect together with the driver itself, but with the same result:

**C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\xerial\sqlite-jdbc\main\module.xml**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.xerial.sqlite-jdbc">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqlite-dialect-0.1.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Has somebody a working solution for this problem? Meantime I will reread again the related sections from WildFly documentation :-)

Best regards,
Kérdezösködő Indián

Comment: I think its a jboss service issue. Can you start jboss without your application and check if running without any errors?

Comment: Yes, I can. And all the other deployed applications are working fine.

Comment: Ok, then jboss is not the problem here. Can you post your hibernate.cfg.xml config in your question by editing it? Where are you setting the dialect?

Comment: I have only a persistence.xml, added to the question.

Comment: @KérdezösködőIndián, which Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: 5.0.7.Final, this comes with WildFly 10.0.0.Final.

Comment: It seems that the `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` is necessary. So starts up the persistence unit.

Answer (score 8):

On error

> Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect]

I solve this problem with any change int application.properties:

```
# for sqlite3
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:test_db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
# old wrond value
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
# nedd value
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```

and this block in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.gwenn</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.30.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Support From Hibernate over SQLite has stopped, and you can fix this by including external dependencies.

Add this lines in your gradle.build file.

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.kemitix/sqlite-dialect'}
}
```

And

```
compile group: 'net.kemitix', name: 'sqlite-dialect', version: '0.1.0'
```

And then, set your properties as
spring.jpa.database-platform:org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect

Answer (score 0):

This works for Hibernate 5:

https://github.com/ZsoltFabok/sqlite-dialect

Maven:  https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.zsoltfabok/sqlite-dialect/1.0/jar

Usage: `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect`

Answer (score -1):

For PostgresSQL (working for me)

We need to add the postgres JDBC driver to Wildfly 10 as we define datasources inside Wildfly.

Create the following directory wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/org/postgresql/main/
Copy the module.xml into wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/org/postgresql/main/

Copy postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar(can download) into wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/org/postgresql/main/

---- module.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
```